# AJAX request from Internet Explorer 11 to a nodejs server running behind Apache proxy aborts randomly

Tags: ajax, node.js, apache, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

On a page that uses angular, after a user action, a get request is made to the server to get some json data. Sometimes the request fails on Internet Explorer 11 (I have not tested on other versions yet). It works on Firefox without any issue. This request failure seems to happen randomly and I cannot put a finger on the cause. Here is the screen shot of aborted request:

[image: Aborted AJAX get request with no method name on Internet Explorer 11]

**Server Side**

This particular api runs on nodejs but the request is proxied through Apache for this particular domain with following config settings

```
...
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
 ...
```

Also, KeepAlive is on and KeepAliveTimeOut is 3 seconds (it was off before and i had the same problem)

What may be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

When I took the apache out of the equation so that the requests are made to nodejs server directly, problem seems to have gone away. I suppose I am doing something wrong with using apache as proxy server(however, it seems to work on firefox/chrome without problems).

I would still appreciate a response about how to make it work with apache as proxy.

**Update:**
Now, I am running nginx as reverse proxy and all is fine. No such aborts.